# Can I cache images these are refreshing after time interval in php?

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I am working on chat application and I have user profile images these are refreshing after 1s interval using Js.
After 1s my Js script send request to server and on server side it check if user have profile image in database then it send all users profile images.
This make user profile images blinking after 1s.
I want to cache user profile images so that it can't load images from server again and again. First time it load from server and cache images in browser and then for each request it get images from cache not from server.
But when user update their profile image then it must load updated profile image from server.

Please tell if it's possible..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you updating the profile images every second? If the images hasn't change, don't update it?

Comment: I updated images every second because if user1 update its profile image then it will also show updated image on user2 screen...

Comment: As I said, don't update the images if they haven't changed. When fetching the data, just fetch the data that has been updated since the last request.

Comment: Please give me an example.. I am pretty new in web so please

Answer (score 0):

You can use this meta tag for caching images :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public" />
```

Comment: Ok well but when user update profile image then it will show previous cached image not the updated how can I fix it..

Comment: So the solution is don't update the images after js request, you must update just the content.

Comment: If I can't update the images then other online users will never see the last updated image of user.